# How to use PiCloud with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

How to use opencv on picloud?

this simple numpy test works

```
import cloud
import numpy as np
import time

data= np.random.rand(100,4)

t0= time.time()
job_id= cloud.call(np.dot,data,data.T)
cloud.join(job_id)
res= cloud.result(job_id)
print (time.time()-t0)
print res.shape

t0= time.time()
res= np.dot(data,data.T)
print (time.time()-t0)
print res.shape
```

but this is not

```
import cv
im= cv.LoadImage("D:\\001_001.tif")

t0= time.time()
job_id= cloud.call(cv.Smooth,im,im)
cloud.join(job_id)
res= cloud.result(job_id)
print (time.time()-t0)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test_cloud.py", line 13,
 in <module>
    cloud.join(job_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cloud\cloud.py", line 721, in join
    neededJids = filter_xrange_list(resultFilter, neededJids)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cloud\util\xrange_helper.py", line 167, in
 filter_xrange_list
    if func(elm):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cloud\cloud.py", line 719, in resultFilter

    return filterJob(jid, status) # filter out done jobs; raise exception on err
ored jobs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cloud\cloud.py", line 668, in filterJob
    raise CloudException(exception, jid=jid, status=status, hint=hint)
cloud.cloud.CloudException: Job 8: Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f162e1d3720:
  File "/usr/local/picloud/.employee/pimployee/job_util.py", line 136 in process
_job
  File "/usr/local/picloud/.employee/job_task.py", line 74 in <module>

TIP: It looks like your program crashed. If it is not clear how to solve this, p
lease file a support ticket (https://www.picloud.com/accounts/support/).
```

**Update:** also not working with cv2 interface.

```
import cv2

im= cv2.imread("D:\\001_001.tif")

t0= time.time()
job_id= cloud.call(cv2.blur,im,im)
cloud.join(job_id)
res= cloud.result(job_id)
print (time.time()-t0)
```

Answer (score 0):

the *old* cv api is using IplImages, not numpy arrays.

instead of:

```
import cv
im= cv.LoadImage("D:\\001_001.tif")
```

you should use:

```
import cv2
im= cv2.imread("D:\\001_001.tif")
```

avoid the outdated cv module in general, it won't be available in the next version of opencv